# AppSetting configuration value for 'ChannelPoolMaxIdleAgeHours' (24 hours) is too large for the current configuration issue?

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to restart my service that time i am facing below error. I don't know what is this issue.

Can you please any one if you understand this issue. Please help me to solve this.

```
2016-07-15 11:30:55,128 FATAL:  [5] Exception occurred during startup. Shutting down.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: AppSetting configuration value for 'ChannelPoolMaxIdleAgeHours' (24 hours) is too large for the current configuration value of 'ReceiveTimoutMinutes' (720 minutes). Please ensure ChannelPoolMaxIdleAgeHours is <= ReceiveTimeoutMinutes/120.
   at Proficy.Platform.Core.Server.ProficyServer.ValidateAppSettings()
   at Proficy.Platform.Core.Server.ProficyServer.OnStart(String[] args) [Server.Service]
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <configuration> <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Comment: We need to see the content of the config. Seems like the values of those two settings are not ***ChannelPoolMaxIdleAgeHours is <= ReceiveTimeoutMinutes/120***

Comment: Below is my app.config file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>

Comment: Edit the question and add it there

Comment: ok thanks for your information

Comment: Updated successfully